# Как избежать FloodWait

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

```
app = Client("my_account")
async def main():
    async with app:
        async for member in app.get_chat_members('chatname'):
            id = (member.user.id)
            try:
                me = await app.get_chat(id)
                print(f'{me.id}|{me.username}|{me.bio}')
            except FloodWait as e:
                await asyncio.sleep(e.value)
app.run(main())
```

Как избежать FloodWait я сейчас использую ожидания в 25 секунд
Но это слишком долго
Я парсю группы и для этого сейчас моя программа слишком медленная
Как можно грамотно избежать блокировки чтобы я смог спарсить группу быстро

Answer (score 0):

Ваш скрипт итак слишком быстрый. Его нельзя улучшить. Разве что, можно взять несколько аккаунтов и распределить всех участников между ними.